# integral of greatest integer function of trig form

Tags: real-analysis

I have this dilemma on this problem, pls i need some help

this is it;

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|cos(2x)|d(sinx) $$

i applied integration by part and i have this

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|cos(2x)|d(sinx) +\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(sinx)d|cos(2x)| = |cos(2(\frac{\pi}{2})|(sin\frac{\pi}{2})-|cos(2(-\frac{\pi}{2})|(sin(-\frac{\pi}{2}))$$

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|cos(2x)|d(sinx) = |cos(2(\frac{\pi}{2})|(sin\frac{\pi}{2})-|cos(2(-\frac{\pi}{2}))|(sin(-\frac{\pi}{2}))-\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(sinx)d|cos(2x)|$$

$$ = 2-\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(sinx)d|cos(2x)|$$

how do i go about simplifying the integral; i mean 
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(sinx)d|cos(2x)|$$
appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: You refer to the "greatest integer function" in the title, but not in the body. Did you mean, "absolute value function"? If so, please edit the title.

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts does not apply because $|\cos{2 x}|$ is not differentiable in the integration region.  Rather, split the integration region up so as to lose the absolute value.  To wit:

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d(\sin{x}) \, |\cos{2 x}| &= -2 \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}  d(\sin{x}) \,\cos{2 x}+ 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/4} d(\sin{x}) \,\cos{2 x} \,\end{align}$$

Note that the integrals can be split like this because $d(\sin{x}) = \cos{x}\,  dx$.

To evaluate each integral, use $\cos{2 x} - 1 - 2 \sin^2{x}$.

**ADDENDUM**

Here is a plot of $\cos{2 x}$ and $|\cos{2 x}|$:

[image]

Note that $|\cos{2 x}|=-\cos{2 x}$ when $-\pi/2 \le x \le -\pi/4$ and $\pi/4 \le x \le \pi/2$.

Comment: pls did u compute the limit of integration?

Comment: @LawrenceOrewa: I split the interval of integration into places where $\cos{2 x}$ is negative and positive.

Comment: still grappling on splitting integral. take a look at this; $$\int_{0)^{\frac{3\pi}{2} $$

Comment: Where is $\cos{2 x} \lt 0$?  When $2 x \in [\pi/2,\pi]$ and $[-\pi,\pi/2]$.  There, you replace $|\cos{2 x}|$ by $-\cos{2 x}$.

Comment: really do appreciate ur assistance so far but i don't know why am not getting it, could u show by example pls.

Comment: @LawrenceOrewa: not sure what is the trouble, but see if my edit helps.